# Warning whilst putting IBOutlet buttons in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, iboutlet

I am trying to put 9 buttons in an array, I get the error

> Cannot use instance member 'oneOne' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

9 times for every button, here is my code. I would greatly appreciate any help, I am a newbie at iOS development.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBOutlet var oneOne: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var twoOne: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var threeOne: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var oneTwo: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var twoTwo: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var threeTwo: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var oneThree: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var twoThree: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var threeThree: UIButton!

var allSpaces = [oneOne,twoOne,threeOne,oneTwo,twoTwo,threeTwo,oneThree,twoThree,threeThree]

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, use IB to add those buttons to an Outlet Collection.

Comment: Add `lazy` in front of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `lazy var` declaration for `allSpaces` or make an `@IBOutlet` collection:

```
lazy var allSpaces = [oneOne,twoOne,threeOne,oneTwo,twoTwo,threeTwo,oneThree,twoThree,threeThree]
```

or:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttons: [UIButton]! // Connect your outlets here.
```